# What does "CONCOC" stand for?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, significado-em-contexto

I wanted to check if "Concoc" was already a word or a brand name for anything, and it seems it is used in Brazillian videos, but I can't find it in a Portuguese dictionary.

Does CONCOC mean anything?
I don't speak any Portuguese so I can't deduce the meaning from context.

[image: google video results for "concoc"]

Comment: It is a name of a School. No means. I believe it is an Acronym or initials

Comment: @Peixoto can you add an answer?

Comment: CONCOC refers to the COC teaching system, originally Brazilian but bought by Pearson and CON is concurso, a competitive exam. So, the COC schools have competitive exams (concursos) to give scholarships to kids at various levels of education. So, CONCOC means: a competitive exam given by a COC school for purposes of bestowing scholarships.

Comment: @Lambie this comment could be an answer. Why don't you write one? I think it is more complete than the existing one.

Comment: @RafaelTavares OK, I put it in. Someone has been downvoting my answers. That just bores me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concoc is a brand in Brazil. They are schools around the country. Usually, they give scholarship, so, these videos are tips to the test for scholarship.

Here part of a news about it:

> O aulão CONCOC ocorre no Cinesystem do Shopping Iguatemi, em
>   Florianópolis, das 8h às 12h. Das  14h às 17h, do mesmo dia, será
>   aplicada uma prova de conhecimentos gerais, na sede do COC, para os
>   alunos concorrerem a bolsas de estudo na unidade. Todos os
>   participantes da prova ganharão descontos na mensalidade do ensino
>   médio.

In a quick and free translate:  A class preparation for scholarship happened.

Source: [AO VIVO: assista ao Aulão CONCOC em parceria com DC neste sábado](http://dc.clicrbs.com.br/sc/vozes/noticia/2016/09/ao-vivo-assista-ao-aulao-concoc-em-parceria-com-dc-neste-sabado-7552327.html?pagina=8)

Comment: This is most definitely not a brand. A brand is a marca [de produto].

Comment: ConCOC stands for  "concurso COC". It claims to be copyrighted in Brazil. I have not checked if the claim is true. At the very bottom of https://concoc.com.br/sobre

Answer (score 5):

CONCOC refers to the COC teaching system, originally Brazilian but bought by Pearson and CON is concurso, a competitive exam. So, the COC schools have competitive exams (concursos) to give scholarships to kids at various levels of education. So, CONCOC means: a competitive exam given by a COC school for purposes of bestowing scholarships.

Isso é o que quer dizer.

Comment: Today, the good angels are out playing. :)

Comment: There you go. :-D